# Jetpack Compose - Box with scrollable content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My Composable looks as below:

```
fun Screen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        ) {
            // Content which is pretty large in height (Scrollable)
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        ) {
            // A button (CTA for next screen)
        }
    }
}
```

The requirement is let the CTA stick to the bottom of the screen and the actual content be scrollable. However, as per my implementation, if the actual content gets bigger in height, it pushes the CTA off the screen.

How do I make the CTA stick to the screen?

Answer (score 15):

You can use a `Column` instead of a `Box` applying the `weight` modifier to the 1st nested `Column`.
Something like:

```
Column() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .weight(1f)
    ) {
        // Content which is pretty large in height (Scrollable)
    }
    Column(
    ) {
        // A button (CTA for next screen)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows the CTA at the bottom of screen, but the main content doesn't get scrolled.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Just tried. The content in the 1st `Column` with the modifier 
 `verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()` scrolls without any issue

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what if I want to have `A button (CTA for next screen)` on top of screen instead of bottom?